# How to properly change layout for horizontal view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout

Hi I'm trying to create this kind of layout for my app.

[image: layout]
So as you can see from the image UICollectionView has to move to the right of the screen and change in size. Also all the UIViews change in size when orientation changes.

I have tried to change the location of the elements in the code and then call that method whenever the view appears:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        // portrait
        [self portraitUISetup];

    } else {
        // landscape
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(landscapeUISetup)
                                                     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
}

-(void)portraitUISetup
{
    self.flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;

    self.flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 18.0f;
    self.flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(167, 254);
    self.flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 40, 52, 18);

    CGRect rect = self.textView.frame;
    rect.size.width = 355;
    rect.size.height = 438;
    rect.origin.x = 373;
    rect.origin.y = 230;
    self.textView.frame = rect;

    rect = self.collectionView.frame;
    rect.size.width = 768;
    rect.size.height = 327;
    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.origin.y = 697;
    self.collectionView.frame = rect;

    rect = self.slideshow.frame;
    rect.size.width = 768;
    rect.size.height = 181;
    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.origin.y = 20;
    self.slideshow.frame = rect;

    rect = self.selectedIssueCover.frame;
    rect.size.width = 293;
    rect.size.height = 438;
    rect.origin.x = 40;
    rect.origin.y = 230;
    self.selectedIssueCover.frame = rect;

}

-(void)landscapeUISetup
{
    self.flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;

    self.flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 49.0f;
    self.flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(167, 254);
    self.flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 23, 0, 25);
    self.collectionView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;

    CGRect rect = self.collectionView.frame;
    rect.size.width = 217;
    rect.size.height = 539;
    rect.origin.x = 810;
    rect.origin.y = 229;
    self.collectionView.frame = rect;

    rect = self.slideshow.frame;
    rect.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    rect.size.height = 181;
    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.origin.y = 20;
    self.slideshow.frame = rect;

    rect = self.selectedIssueCover.frame;
    rect.size.width = 333;
    rect.size.height = 498;
    rect.origin.x = 40;
    rect.origin.y = 233;
    self.selectedIssueCover.frame = rect;

    rect = self.textView.frame;
    rect.size.width = 355;
    rect.size.height = 498;
    rect.origin.x = 414;
    rect.origin.y = 233;
    self.textView.frame = rect;

}
```

**The problem** I have encountered with this method is that as soon as I push to another view this view is reset to the portrait one(probably to the one set in the storyboard) even if the device is in landscape.

So what would the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Put your layout logic inside `viewWillLayoutSubviews` instead of registering for rotation events.

Comment: So I would just set up the landscape there? Because that doesn't work.

Comment: You would set up your layout there. You would decide which layout to apply based on the value of `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`. Please describe what doesn't work.

Comment: Just tried to move that orientation check from `viewWillAppear` to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and same issue.

Comment: @Kirill you should probably try `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  `WillLayout` gets called before layout and will undo any changes you make.

Comment: Now the UICollectionView is pushed to the right out off the screen when I change from landscape to portrait. Pushing to another view is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Interface Builder it's really easy to setup two different layouts based on the size class.  If you change your simulated metrics at the bottom from `wAny hAny` to `wRegular hAny` and setup some new layout constraints it will automatically switch between the two at run time.

Comment: I'm not using size class or Xcode 6. Also the layout is for iPad so it wouldn't work. I will change the image.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was with the interface check. I changed that a little and used @Ian MacDonald's suggestions to use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Here is my solution that works now.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||  orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        [self landscapeUISetup];

    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        [self portraitUISetup];
    }

}
```

Comment: I doubt that's going to work for very many people; you can't invalidate the layout AND reapply layout attributes without using UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext, which is the method designed for the very problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is with `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext`. See How to invalidate flow collection view layout on rotation for a sample implementation:

http://aplus.rs/2015/how-to-invalidate-flow-collection-view-layout-on-rotation/

To-wit:

Say you want to have grid layout with cells always half the size of the screen’s width. You want to maintain that layout in both portrait and landscape. Since iOS 8 that can’t be easier, with the right incantations.

First, subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`; then, add the following method to it:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext *)invalidationContextForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {

  UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext *context = (UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext *)[super invalidationContextForBoundsChange:newBounds];
  context.invalidateFlowLayoutDelegateMetrics = (
                                                 CGRectGetWidth(newBounds) != CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.bounds) ||
                                                 CGRectGetHeight(newBounds) != CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.bounds)
                                                 );
  return context;
}
```

The key here is casting returned context from super as `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext` which allows you to toggle the `invalidateFlowLayoutDelegateMetrics` property. That will tell UIKit that it should re-query FlowLayout’s delegate for the sizes.

In the collection view controller, make sure it’s set to adopt `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol and then add this delegate call:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                layout:(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout
sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  return CGSizeMake(floor(self.view.bounds.size.width/2.0), 88);
}
```